# Attendance widget - using html css and bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a widget called attendance which will be used as month-wise. e.g jan-dec
I already designed and coded using html, css and bootstrap. 
like below
[image]

problem: now i want make it functional, e.g on left-arrow click goes to previous month and on right-arrow click goes to next month. On current month right-arrow will be grayed-out (disabled) because there will be no attendance for future.

Hope I am clear, if not please let me know. I will update.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know , you need to write a click event and change according to it  by creating array

```
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
```

you need to hard-code it, and add the jquery  data attribute and do the functionality 
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/